# Как создать пару вводимых значений через цикл?

Tags: python

Задача:
Толик является владельцем обувного магазина. В его магазине есть количество обуви.
У него есть список, содержащий размер каждой обуви, которая есть в его магазине.
Есть количество клиентов, готовых платить сумму денег только в том случае, если они получат обувь желаемого размера.

Ваша задача — посчитать, сколько денег заработал Толик.

Первая строка содержит, количество обуви.
Вторая строка содержит разделенный пробелами список всех размеров обуви в магазине.
Третья строка содержит, количество клиентов.
Следующие строки содержат разделенные пробелами значения размера обуви желаемого заказчиком, и цена обуви.
Выведите сумму денег, заработанную Толиков.

Образец ввода:

10

2 3 4 5 6 8 7 6 5 18

6

6 55

6 45

6 55

4 40

18 60

10 50

Вывод:

200

Объяснение:
Покупатель 1 : Купил обувь 6-го размера за 55 долларов.
Покупатель 2 : Купил обувь 6-го размера за 45 долларов.
Покупатель 3 : Размер 6 больше не доступен, поэтому не покупайте.
Покупатель 4 : Купил обувь четвертого размера за 40 долларов.
Покупатель 5 : Купил обувь 18-го размера за 60 долларов.
Покупатель 6 : Размер 10 недоступен, поэтому не покупайте.

Всего заработано денег = 200

```
number_of_shoes = int(input())
all_shoe_size = set(map(int, input().split(' ')))
print(all_shoe_size)
number_of_clients = int(input())

lst1 = []
lst2 = []
lst3 = []
lst4 = []
lst5 = []
lst6 = []

for i in range(number_of_clients):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    lst1.append(a)
    lst1.append(b)
print(f'lst 1: {lst1}')
print(f'lst 2: {lst2}')
```

```
#10
#2 3 4 5 6 8 7 6 5 18
#6
#6 55   Купил обувь 6-го размера за 55 долларов
#6 45   Купил обувь 6-го размера за 45 долларов
#6 55   Размер 6 больше не доступен, поэтому не покупайте.
#4 40   Купил обувь четвертого размера за 40 долларов
#18 60  Купил обувь 18-го размера за 60 долларов
#10 50  Размер 10 недоступен, поэтому не покупайте

#200
```

Как сделать нужное колличество списков зная сколько вводов потребуется? И как занести значения в каждый список используя цикл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужно много списков, этого же не требуют в задаче. Достаточно одного с кортежами, или для наглядности двух, как в примере ниже (это не самый эффективный способ, но он нагляден, и для учебных примеров я предпочитаю его).
Просто чуть переделайте своё решение, вы в этом же направлении и шли.

```
import sys

size_of_client = [None] * number_of_clients
price_of_client = [None] * number_of_clients 

for i in range(number_of_clients):
    size_of_client[i], price_of_client[i] = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
```

Дополню примером кортежа, о котором в комментарии спросили.
В данном случае можно так. Должно быть возможным и в односточник упаковать, полагаю, просто задача же не на это.

```
import sys

request_of_client = []
for _ in range(number_of_clients):
    a, b = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    request_of_client.append((a,b))
```

Сделал всё же и односточником со списком из кортежей:

```
request_of_client = [(tuple (i for i in tuple (map(int, input().split())))) for _ in range (number_of_clients)]
```

Comment: Ок попробую так

Comment: А почему нет? Вот работающий пример внес в ответ. Или есть специфические какие-то вопросы?

Comment: Короче, чем в одну строку уже не сделаю:-) - можете принимать ответ, если больше нет вопросов:-)

Comment: Класс, благодарю :)

Comment: Опесатку нашел - лишний `tuple` не убрал:-) Вот чуть короче: `request_of_client = [(tuple (i for i in map(int, input().split()))) for _ in range (number_of_clients)]`